# Authenticating with scopes but getting 403 and 405 errors on API calls. Looking for guidance

Tags: autodesk-forge

Authenticating with both of these functions, both return access token, neither works for API calls.   e.g. calls to get_autodesk_usage_summary return with 403 error, others with 405 error.

## set the variables, pulls some from env

```
AUTODESK_CLIENT_ID = ENV['AUTODESK_CLIENT_ID']AUTODESK_CLIENT_SECRET = ENV['AUTODESK_CLIENT_SECRET']AUTODESK_URL = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/'AUTODESK_USERINFO_URL = 'https://api.userprofile.autodesk.com/'AUTODESK_TOKENFLEX_URL = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/tokenflex/v1/'AUTODESK_V1_URL = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/'
```

## authenticate the user

```
def authenticate():
    HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    BODY = {'client_id': AUTODESK_CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret': AUTODESK_CLIENT_SECRET, 'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'scope': ['code:all', 'data:search', 'data:write', 'account:read', 'user:read']}
    auth_url = f"{AUTODESK_V1_URL}/authenticate"
    res = requests.post(url=auth_url, data=BODY, headers=HEADERS)
    js = res.json()
    return js
```

## get an access token

```
def get_autodesk_access_token():

to_encode = f"{AUTODESK_CLIENT_ID}:{AUTODESK_CLIENT_SECRET}".encode("ascii")
encoded = base64.b64encode(to_encode)URL = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token'HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept':'application/json','Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded.decode()}
BODY = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'scope': ['code:all', 'data:search',\
data:write', 'account:read', 'user:read']}
res = requests.post(url=URL, headers=HEADERS, data=BODY)
jj = res.json()
return jj
```

## get usage summary

```
def get_autodesk_usage_summary(access_token:str = None, contract_number:str=None):
    my_header = {}
    my_header['Authorization'] = f"Bearer {access_token}"
    my_header['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.auth = OAuth2BearerToken(access_token)
        res = s.get(f"{AUTODESK_TOKENFLEX_URL}/usage/:{contract_number}/summary")
        if res.ok:
            js = res.json()
            return js
        else:
            print(f"response = {res.status_code}. error.")
```

```
"""{'access_token': 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY0RE9XMnJoOE9tbjNpdk1NU0xlNGQ2VHEwUV9SUzI1NiIsInBpLmF0bSI6Ijd6M2gifQ.QiOiJZSTdFem5wdkIwcjNBem5yS0JXZVpIVE5iMUFmM1F0TSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXV0b2Rlc2suY29tL2F1ZC9hand.m1jpIcYcJiHLE2Gtd-XEkCzMTl3wi1SJx5BXpD-Zogm7Po7Sy7yDK9jrX7MTOfOFofekVSbeluXw4mwJrcM_OTlTewrDVGMIZbd1RQ4fjI9C10dy60lL9ECDnx8V_iY_10GRXDuzt9KpO8FHwf4NEZ23Lfqp-FKeeb3ZImzXr2wpEfJSIF3ituCdp59Y4wi7s2OU4vPuzAPlp13h03VsbebtU3cfJUZVUuBLcb4HFvW8TLTowqo2XJ7HGap-IS2KQSXeNW6i_Cmzj0iCwGUdnEHNq2ajk2bssx-xbSpDKvtGrQZagTZ3mTdOu01A9NbVgGN0SYGL59ay1ljNvAqXNQ','expires_in': 3599,'token_type': 'Bearer'}"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Token Flex APIs? Are you one of the EBA (enterprise customer) ?
Note : - The API enables enterprise customers to access their Autodesk Token Flex consumption, product usage, and contract details.